# Wordpress Image Editor not working - conflict?

Tags: media, editor, images

I am having a strange issue with the built in wordpress image editor. I have no problem uploading files or preforming any other media functions. The only thing I seem to be unable to do is utilize the image "edit" capabilities (the area where you can crop, resize, rotate...)

When I click on "edit" for an image I see the editor and I see the thumbnail on the right, wordpress just won't show me the actual image in the main area and thus I can't utilizing any of the editing capabilities.

I am assuming this must be some type of JavaScript conflict however I not sure the best way to diagnose this other than what I have already done (disabling all plugins and ensuring no functions.php file is modifying a setting or including other javascript).

How can I diagnose this issue to see what might be going wrong?

Comment: It could also be a PHP issue.  If you don't have the right modules or version of PHP installed, WordPress is built to "decompose gracefully" ... meaning that certain bonus features become disabled if your system's setup doesn't support them.  Can you run `phpinfo` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) on your site and report back what your system's using?

Comment: Open the page in Firefox with Firebug Add-On installed. Check for Javascript Errors in the log. Please report back if you have any Javascript Errors.

Comment: @eamann @hakre Thanks guys - i ended up figured out what was going on through a great deal of trial and error. See my attached answer in case your interested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have actually managed to resolve my own problem. For anyone else that might ever read this the problem which caused this was that my `functions.php` file had a closing

```
?>
```

at the very end. For whatever reason this is what cause the issue and by removing this last line it was working again.

Comment: You might have had some characters (whitespace) after that `?>`. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12307 and http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10633

Comment: I had the same problem - and this solution (removing the ?>) at the end of my theme functions.php worked for me, great! Thanks very much for this advice.

Comment: I have this exact problem right now however I wasn't as lucky as you, I have removed any closing `?>` tags and whitespace from my functions file and all files that I have included into my functions file and I still have the problem.  Very frustrating.  I have no javascript errors either

Comment: This helped me too. I was wondering what the issue was. Although, it was not function.php for me. I had to remove them (?>) in all the php files I was including.

Comment: another reason might be that php5-gd was not installed. install the module and restart apache to get it working.

Comment: I actually had a space before the opening `<?php` in a plugin file... Brutal typos.

Comment: Nice! As of February 2022, removing the closing "?>" tag worked for me also. I was getting pretty frustrated with it! So, from twelve years later, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is the PHP closing tag (`?>`) in `functions.php`.

However, if in `functions.php` there are many inclusions which in turn include other PHP files, it is unthinkable to remove all PHP closing tag in all files.

So, my advice is add in the first line of `functions.php` the php function `ob_start()` and in the last line `ob_end_clean()` by removing the closing PHP tag.

Everything will work perfectly.

Comment: You'd suggest output buffering to mask the problem instead of correcting the PHP?

Comment: See the regex at the bottom of this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4499749/1982136 - to remove the closing PHP tag in all files.