# Wordpress crop tool greyed out

Tags: images, editor

The wordpress crop tool is greyed out for me in Firefox 3.6 (and IE7/8). I have disabled firefox add-ons and tried the solution here:

[Wordpress Image Editor not working - conflict?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/wordpress-image-editor-not-working-conflict)

But this hasn't resolved the issue. Anyone know how wordpress determines whether to enable the crop button?

WP version is 3.0.1

thanks,

Comment: Just realised that the button is disabled until you start dragging. The issue was caused by one of the installed plugins (I think). Just need to figure out which one now.

Comment: This is usually fixed by installing the "gd" library on the server. Your host needs to do something like `yum install php-gd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% sure this was caused by the firephp plugin.

Comment: did deactivating the firephp plugin help you? can you link the firephp plugin?

Comment: yep. Link is http://inchoo.net/wordpress/wordpress-firephp-plugin/

Comment: Then probably the WordPress FirePHP is not smart enough to know when it should shut up (in AJAX requests for example).

Answer (score 6):

For me, the button became available once I clicked and dragged the mouse cursor over part of the image to select an area to crop.

Comment: Wow, this is very unintuitive UI.

Comment: Yes, yes, a dramatic user interface. After setting the cropped area, I had to click the "Cropped" button again, after which the "Save" button was available. Look at *@Mike Kormendy* answer  for step by step answer

Answer (score 5):

The crop tool and edit-image interface is not as intuitive as it could be.

For anyone looking for why the crop tool is deactivated and the save button is greyed-out, here are the steps for getting the crop tool to work:

1. edit the image you wish to crop
2. click the crop button above the image
3. drag your area of the image you wish to crop the image to
4. **click the crop button AGAIN**
5. notice now that the image has been cropped, now hit the save button.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else where codecowboy's solution did not resolve the problem try this...

I had a very similar issue to what I think your experiencing over there... After hours and hours of trying to resolve it by coincidence I figured out that the problem was an extra space at the bottom of my custom functions.php file.

So... go and try this. Open your themes main folder and look for your functions.php file. Now go to the very bottom of the page and look for the closing **?>** php tag. Now, make sure that there are NO tabs, spaces or line returns after the **>** including any comments or anything extra.

For me this fixed my issue and I think its a wordpress problem. If your still having the issue check to see if your calling any external php files within your functions.php file and if so do the same steps as listed above. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This is not specific to WordPress, but to PHP. You cannot set HTTP headers if you already sent output. Having content outside PHP tags sends this output (as expected), and the crop functionality probably depends on Ajax with specific headers or content (not prefixed with empty lines). The solution is to leave off the closing PHP tag, this is still valid PHP, but prevents these kind of errors.

Comment: Very true... Still it's something I noticed so I figured I would share

Comment: Even better, avoid the closing PHP tag altogether. It's not required, and leaving it out can help to prevent this problem. More background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag/