# "Unable to create new image" error in wordpress dashboard image editor

Tags: images

My server is nginx and wordpress version is 3.8.1. I can upload images but when I try to edit the image (scale, crop) it gives below error and doesn't show picture.

I have tried with 400kb to 1mb picture both has same problem.

I found on internet that it can happen because of GD library is not available. I have installed GD library but still getting same error. Also tried [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/wordpress-image-editor-not-working-conflict) but no luck.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you please try temporarily turning on debugging with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in `wp-config.php` to see if this gives any more hints.

Comment: I would guess that you don't have enough memory. Image editing in WP can use a lot.

Comment: @vancoder How to check it?

Comment: @kraftner getting this http://pastebin.com/BrEsdThP

Comment: Other than indicating that the advanced-category-excluder plugin is crap, I dont think that helps

Comment: Disable all plugins and see if that helps.

Comment: I would also suggest to completely delete advanced-category-excluder. As vancoder said, it is crap

Comment: I have de-activated all plugins but problem is still there

Comment: I have changed theme to wordpress default theme, but still problem is there

Comment: I have the same problem. Any update on this?