# Custom "Uploads" Dir: "Edit Image" in Media Library broken

Tags: javascript, media-library, uploads, media-modal

#### Directory Structure

I have customized my (local) install (dev box). The current directory structure is:

```
 ./root
  |- wp (WordPress Core root)
    \
    |- wp-config.php
  |- wp-content (Content and Vendor root)
    \
    |- mu-plugins (...)
    |- themes (...)
    |- plugins (...)
    |- uploads (Custom uploads dir)
    |- vendor (Composer installed libraries)
  |- index.php (loads ~/wp/index.php > require( dirname(__FILE__).'/wp/wp-blog-header.php' ); )
```

#### Config

In my `wp-config.php`, I have the following setup:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL',      'http://example.dev/wp' );
define( 'WP_HOME',         WP_SITEURL );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',  './../../wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL',  'http://example.dev/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR',   '../../wp-content/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL',   WP_CONTENT_URL.'/plugins' );
define( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR', '../../wp-content/mu-plugins' );
define( 'WPMU_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL.'/mu-plugins' );
```

It is a single site install and none of the following constants is defined (and therefore falls back to default): `UPLOADBLOGSDIR`, `UPLOADS`, `BLOGUPLOADDIR`.

#### Filters

As @Sven (Hofmann) asked me in chat: The only plugin running on the `*_url` filters is one mu-plugin that sets up the new themes directory:

```
add_filter( 'theme_root_uri', 'switch_theme_root_local' );
add_filter( 'theme_root',     'switch_theme_root_local' );
```

As you can see, there's nothing that can conflict with internal URls.

### Problem

Step 1) When I go to the "Media Library" and click/open an attachment, the modal opens like normal and displays the media file (or in the problematic case: the image).

> [image: Attachment Details - WordPress Media Library]

Step 2) Hit the *"Edit Image"* Link above and the following screen (modal replacement) appears. Note the broken image. I opened Chromes dev tools to show the el and attributes/path.

> [image: Editing an Attachment - WordPress Media Library]

I have no idea how to debug this and/or where the broken links origin could be. I assume that this is *burried* somewhere in WordPress least documented parts: JavaScript templates for the media library.

Comment: Are you using `defined` instead of `define` in `wp-config.php` ? I don't see this behavior on my skeleton installs.

Comment: @birgire No, that's just a typo. I use a .env-file and eited that out to not confuse anyone. Fixed.

Comment: This is a sidenote, but I believe the console log error is a common one only to Chrome - [Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515991/chrome-err-cache-miss), [Related Article](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599).

Comment: ok, I guess you could tackle `stream_preview_image()` ,armed with `exit()` and `var_dump()` ;-) ps: it also looks like you got a different setup than mine, since I don't use relative paths like './../../wp-content', so I guess your config file is in some subdirectory.

Comment: @birgire The `.env` is in the root, one level below `wp` and `wp-content`, but the `wp-config.php` is inside the `wp` dir.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I'm using Chrome 39 right now. Read through the reports and the `net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` error is gone when I access it with the Chrome dev tools already open (as reported in the Chrome bug report). Problem is that it's still broken and it the error now is `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`.

Comment: From the `ajax` request itself, when opened in a stand-alone tab, I get `-1` back.

Comment: There are two cases of `wp_die( -1 );` in the `wp_ajax_imgedit_preview()`, either from `!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)` or `! stream_preview_image($post_id)`.

Comment: please refer to this topic- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/wordpress-image-editor-not-working-conflict

Comment: @VincentWong Thanks for the link, but I didn't change anything. This is a problem with a plain, vanilla install.

Comment: Is there a typo in this example? Or have you intentially provided: `define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',  './../../wp-content' );` instead of `define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',  '../../../wp-content' );`

**Note:** the missing "." in the first example

Comment: I tried but was unable to replicate this. There wasn't quite enough information to replicate the environment verbatim (e.g. I'm confused as to where your wp-config.php resides), but I got the gist of your structure setup and I did not have this issue with images. [Here is a breakdown of my dir structure and what I added to wp-config.php](https://gist.github.com/mboynes/fdc6fb3beaf51a09096a). Given that my setup is similar with two potential differences, I would suggest that this either (1) relates to the location of your wp-config and the relative paths, or (2) is an apache/nginx config issue.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes That could be. It could as well be that the localized script stuff passes something with some hard coded path or URi parts to Backbone & Underscore templates. Not sure as I couldn't find the responsible files.

Answer (score 1):

The uploads dir has its own define in wp-config:

`define( 'UPLOADS', WP_CONTENT_URL.'/customuploads' );`

Comment: Thanks for the hint (updated my question to answer that), but I haven't defined it and it falls back gracefully to cores default. I haven't defined the MU constants either (it's a single site install).