# Image editor is not loading

Tags: images

For some strange reason the embed image editor is not loading

[image: image editor not loading]

1. I've enabled debug in wp-config.php
2. I've disabled 100% of plugins and set a default theme
3. No errors either in Javascript console or the Apache2 error log
4. php-gd is installed
5. imagemagick is installed
6. php-curl is installed
7. I can discard a module missing in the server because I've installed another WP in the same server, and the image editor is working right.

I'm out of ideas, not sure what can be causing this issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue

Checking in the related solutions I found this one
[Wordpress Image Editor not working - conflict?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/wordpress-image-editor-not-working-conflict)

They were talking about a missing ?>, but obviously this was not related because I was using the default theme and not plugins.

But suddenly remembered that I created a simple mu-plugin 10 days ago, and there was the problem: the ?> in the end of that mu-plugin.